# is it possible to get all directives of one type in controller in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a view which contains 20 instances of the same directive, directives are quite big and customizable. I want to be able to list all of those directives dynamicly, so i dont have to create new instance of this directive manually when there will be need to have more of those.

Is it possible to do in AngularJS?

Comment: So, you'd like to see a list of all *currently instantiated* directives?

Comment: Yes :) thats exactly what i want

Comment: I don't know of any specific way of doing this using anything built into Angular, but I should say that I'm not an expert about the ins and outs of it. I imagine you could have your directives register with a list in a service through their link functions, then think of a clever way to deregister them when they're removed from the document.

Comment: TO deregister when they are removed, try the `scope.$on('destroy', ...)` event